# Reset Password For phpMyAdmin

Tags: macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

I recently downloaded XAMPP for macOS and I was able to use phpMyAdmin until I changed the root password. Now when I try accessing it I get an error reading "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" and on top of that I have forgotten the new password. I have read many other posts on this issue but none have seemed to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is for XAMPP on macOS only

You can go phpmyadmin directory inside the main root directory, you can check config.sample.inc.php file and you need to create a new config.inc.php file if already not their.

Copy data from config.sample.inc.php to config.inc.php

You need to make a few changes in the new file:

$cfg ['Servers'] [$i] ['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

Save and restart xampp and check.